# Batching outer products with bsxfun

Tags: matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

Suppose I have 2 vectors and I want to do an outer product. I could use:

```
A=x*y';
```

Or I could use `bsxfun` like that:

```
bsxfun(@times,x,y')
```

But I want to batch outer products. I have 2 matrices, each holds `p` vectors:

```
n=1000;  p=6;
A=rand(n,p);
D=rand(n,p);
```

And I want to calculate all the outer products and sum the results like so:

```
AA=zeros(n,n);

for j=1:p
    AA = AA + A(:,j) * D(:,j).';
end
```

I want to do this more efficiently but I can't figure out how.

Comment: You're looking for a solution in which you combine `bsxfun` with `permute`.

Comment: `C = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(D.',[3 1 2]));` gives me a `1000x6x1000` in very little time, though I'm not sure this is the correct result.

Comment: the result should be 1000x1000

Comment: @Adriaan Good going! So, after that, get rid of the second dim with `sum(C,2)`, thus simulating matrix-multplication with `bxsfun`.

Comment: @Divakar thanks for the hint. I'll type up an answer tonight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just multiply the two matrices together:

```
n=1000;  p=6;
A=rand(n,p);
D=rand(n,p);

way1=zeros(n,n);

for j=1:p
    way1 = way1 + A(:,j) * D(:,j).';
end

way2 = A * D.';

any(way1(:) ~= way2(:))
```

Comment: good solution, though I'd not use `j` as a [variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab). I'll do a `timeit` tonight to see which is faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bsxfun` after all:

```
C = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(D,[3 2 1]));
result = sum(C,2);
```

The first line computes all the outer products between `A` and `D`, the second sums your results together, as requested.

Tested as follows:

```
kk = 1e3;
times1 = zeros(kk,1);
n=1000;  p=6;
A=rand(n,p);
D=rand(n,p);
for ii = 1:kk
    tic
    C = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(D.',[3 1 2]));
    result = sum(C,2);
    times1(ii) = toc;
end
mean(times1)
```

`bsxfun` takes 0.0456s and direct multiplication takes 0.0075s, though I suspect my solution actually does everything 6 times, due to the permute, which is not in the direct multiplication. So per outer product `bsxfun` takes 0.0076s, which is almost equal.

Comment: This is the solution I would have taken. +1.